# What Theme is this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What **Theme** is this that showing in release notes of 1.14?

[image: VS Code Theme]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is Atom One Dark Theme.

You can find it on the marketplace here : 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=akamud.vscode-theme-onedark

Comment: the colors seems like the atom, but background is different.